# Ubuntu 12.04 LTS stops at start

Tags: 12.04, boot, gnome, updates, lts

I've installed the updates, and at the end it asked me to restart the computer. After I restarted, it stops at the booting. All I see is: black screen, Ubuntu 12.04 and the four dots in the middle of the screen. The first dot is orange, and after the fourth dot there's the cursor line.

Answer (score 0):

Does the console working? Pressing ctrl+alt+F1 is showing you tty? If that is working you can start log in there and type `startx`. If that fail you can try `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop`

Comment: startx worked, but it asked that I need to start the display in low graphics mode. I clicked OK, and got a message: edit /etc/default/saned. I navigated there (in the console), and tried "edit saned" but got an error: no write permission for file "saned".

Comment: I found that It caused by the nvidia driver, so I tried to purge and reinstall the driver, but I have the same message.

Answer (score 0):

First things first: the current LTS version of Ubuntu is 14.04. You did not specify any reasonable reasons to use 2-years old version, so I assume that there is no such need. Install 14.04 instead of 12.04, then check if your problem still occurs.